# google maps help

Tags: google-maps

First, I'm trying this through Google (not using API). Want to see if it's possible without API first.

I have a saved map in google which has some points of interest. (ex: national parks)

However, when I search for directions (ex: from: denver, co to: chicago, il) the directions appear, but my saved map (POI's) disappear.

Has or does anyone know how I can modify the URL to have these 2 overlay?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workflow is:
-Go to Google maps  (sign in if necessary)
-Go to My Places
-Select the map you're interested in,
-From here, click on Get directions, type A an B then enter
-Here, you have your directions but your map is lost, but...
-If you click on My Places and your map again, bingo!

Comment: thanks for reply. however, but i want to provide the user a direct link. thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can save directions to the 'My Maps' feature of Google Maps. Once you search for directions, there is a link at the bottom of the direction sidebar titled 'Save to My Maps'. After the directions are saved, you can add custom features to the map in the 'My Maps' editor.

Comment: Casey, I want this to be dynamic. so the directions overlaying the map will be "dynamic". I want to type in to and from. overlay it over the mymap.  thanks tho.

Comment: Gotcha. Sounds like a job for the API.